# Dynamically build query with regex in PyMongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I want to query different fields on MongoDB from Python, like in an advanced search.

Keeping the example simple with just one field, if I query `{'Title': /my string/}` manually on Mongo I get the expected results.

On Python I am doing the following:

```
query = {}
args = request.form
for arg in args:
  key = "{0}".format(arg)
  if args[arg] != "":
    query[key] = "/" + args[arg].lower() + "/"
```

However, the query is like this (note the quotes):

```
{'Title': '/my string/'}
```

So I don't get any results. How can I implement the right query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a list:

```
conditions = [{field: {"$regex": value.lower()}} for field, value in args.items()]
```

Then, join the conditions with `$or` or `$and` (depending on how do you want to apply them):

```
db.col.find({"$or": conditions})
```